# No se me ejecuta array asociativo en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, array, ejecutar

Estoy intentando ejecutar un array asociativo pero al momento de hacerlo la pantalla no me devuelve nada.

Aquí les dejo el código:

```js
let pc1 = {
  nombre = "nahupc",
  procesador = "ryzen 5",
  ram = "8gb"
};

let nombre = pc1["nombre"];
let procesador = pc1["procesador"];
let ram = pc1["ram"];

frase = `el nombre de mi pc es: ${nombre} <br>
el procesador de mi pc es: ${procesador}
<br>
la ram es: ${ram}` ;

document.write(frase);
```

Comment: No existen los arrays asociativos en Javascript, eso es un simple objeto que funciona como una versión sencilla de un *map*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si te fijas en la consola, al correr tu programa, arroja esto:

> ERROR { "message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid shorthand property initializer", ... }

Estás fallando la asignación.
Para asignarlo debes hacerlo de la siguiente forma con `:`, no usando `=`

```js
let pc1 = {
  nombre:"nahupc",
  procesador: "ryzen 5",
  ram: "8gb"
};

let nombre = pc1["nombre"];
let procesador = pc1["procesador"];
let ram = pc1["ram"];

frase = `el nombre de mi pc es: ${nombre} <br>
el procesador de mi pc es: ${procesador}
<br>
la ram es: ${ram}` ;

document.write(frase);
```

Comment: Mil gracias hermano.

Comment: De nada hermano ;) recuerda darme like hermano, su propina es mi sueldo jaja